# How to get the laptop fan cooler to work on an Acer Aspire 5315?

Tags: 11.10, acer, fan

I installed Ubuntu in my Acer Aspire 5315 but now the cooler doesn't work anymore! 
I already read a lot of forums and I tried many suggested solutions but they didn't work.
I already tried with the laptop-mode-tools, to enable the laptop-mode in the acpi-support file, to upgrade the kernel, and a few others.

I managed to start the cooler but it works only sometimes and it doesn't depend on the temperature. And when I restart my computer the cooler doesn't work again and then I don't have the possibility to change the settings again because all of them are already set to be "on".

The only solution that I didn't try is to flash the BIOS, because I'm not an expert and I read that this is quiet dangerous for the motherboard.

Does anybody know any other solution? I want to stay in Ubuntu but my laptop can't work longer than 15 minutes!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There is this bug, now closed because it was opened for Karmik, that is not supported anymore, and I think you should open a new one for Ubuntu 11.10:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/451337

I think you can find a temporary solution using acer_fancontrol, as suggested here:

http://giovanni.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/how-to-solve-fan-problem-on-acer-aspire-5315/